Stripe Money Transfers from Merchant Accounts to Platform Account
I’m working on a project where merchants integrate their Stripe API keys into my system, allowing me to access their analytics and provide consulting on their sales performance. I want to automate charging a consulting fee under specific conditions. Here’s the setup:
If a merchant makes sales over $5000 in a day, I want to charge a flat $10 consultation fee from their account and transfer it to my Stripe account.
Merchants have requested that these charges happen once daily rather than multiple times.
I’m new to Stripe and have looked into Stripe Connect, but I'm having difficulty understanding how to implement this setup, especially when it comes to charging fees on behalf of other accounts.
Specific Questions:
Is it possible to automate these charges directly from the merchant’s account to mine using just their API key?
How should I be using Stripe Connect (if applicable) to facilitate these fee transfers?

You can check the no of transaction done and amount transferred by your customer at the end of each day, and deduct amount according to your conditions instead of deducting amount upfront.
For debiting amount from connected accounts, please refer stripe amount debit from connected accounts. Please make sure to read requirements in the same docs.
